# Delaying JSF form validation

Tags: jsf

In my JSF based web application I have large number of UI input fields on the forms. I try to save the data in to managed beans(and propagate to the database) by submitting the form via ajax calls while the user is still entering the data on the form. When I have validation errors on the page the ajax submit fails to save data to the backend. The usual validation error is required validation on the input fields. This is an annoying issue for me since if the validation of 50th input field fails the data entered in the first field is also not saved.

In all of UI forms we do have a summary page where we show the user entered data before allowing to submit the form. What I would like to know if it is possible to delay the form data validations until the user goes to the summary page. On summary page I want to either display the validation errors or display the read only version of the data. Did anybody encountered this situation or have a solution to this kind of problem?

Comment: how are you validating? Can you show that code? If input is invalid, NOTHING of the form should be lost!

Comment: an example validation is required="true" on an input field.

Comment: This questions is answered on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19712743/skip-required-validation-and-invoke-the-application