# JSF Primefaces - bypass validation in p:ajax

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have a `p:ajax` within a form which triggers on `change` event in a select. Also I have a separate submit button to submit the form.

The form contains multiple validations. I want to bypass all the validations during the `p:ajax` call. Instead all the validations should happen during form submission.

This is my form: **Field1** and **Field2** are *mandatory*. But these validations should be bypassed during `p:ajax` call which in turn renders **Field3** based on the selected **Field2** value.

How can I do this?

```
<h:body>

    <h:form id="formId">

        <p:outputPanel autoUpdate="true">

            <p:message for="field1Id field2Id" />

            <p:panel id="panelId">
                <p:panelGrid>

                    <p:row>
                        <p:column>
                            <h:outputText value="Field1:" />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <p:inputText
                                id="field1Id"
                                required="true"
                                requiredMessage="Field1 is Required!"
                                value="#{testBean.field1}"
                                size="5"
                                maxlength="30" />
                        </p:column>
                    </p:row>

                    <p:row>
                        <p:column>
                            <h:outputText value="Field2:" />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <p:selectOneMenu
                                id="field2Id"
                                value="#{testBean.field2}"
                                required="true"
                                requiredMessage="Field2 is Required!">
                                <f:selectItems
                                    value="#{testBean.fields}"
                                    var="var1"
                                    itemDescription="#{var1.description}"
                                    itemLabel="#{var1.description}"
                                    itemValue="#{var1.id}" />

                                <p:ajax
                                    process="@form"
                                    event="change" />

                            </p:selectOneMenu>
                        </p:column>
                    </p:row>

                    <p:row rendered="#{testBean.field2 > 0}">
                        <p:column>
                            <h:outputText value="Field3:" />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <p:inputText
                                value="#{testBean.field3}"
                                size="5"
                                maxlength="10" />
                        </p:column>
                    </p:row>

                </p:panelGrid>
                <p:commandButton
                    value="Save"
                    action="#{testBean.saveForm()}"
                    process="@form" />
            </p:panel>
        </p:outputPanel>

    </h:form>

</h:body>
```

Comment: That will be difficult to help without seeing anything about your form!

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14335610/jsf-skip-validation-without-immediate-true) will probably help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve by below code. My code just add binding attribute(`binding="{save}"`) at the button, and also change `required="true"` to `required="#{not empty param[save.clientId]}"`

```
<h:body>
    <h:form id="formId">
        <p:outputPanel autoUpdate="true">
            <p:message for="field1Id field2Id" />
            <p:panel id="panelId">
                <p:panelGrid>
                    <p:row>
                        <p:column>
                            <h:outputText value="Field1:" />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <p:inputText
                                id="field1Id"
                                required="#{not empty param[save.clientId]}"
                                requiredMessage="Field1 is Required!"
                                value="#{testBean.field1}"
                                size="5"
                                maxlength="30" />
                        </p:column>
                    </p:row>
                    <p:row>
                        <p:column>
                            <h:outputText value="Field2:" />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <p:selectOneMenu
                                id="field2Id"
                                value="#{testBean.field2}"
                                required="#{not empty param[save.clientId]}"
                                requiredMessage="Field2 is Required!">
                                <f:selectItems
                                    value="#{testBean.fields}"
                                    var="var1"
                                    itemDescription="#{var1.description}"
                                    itemLabel="#{var1.description}"
                                    itemValue="#{var1.id}" />
                                <p:ajax
                                    process="@form"
                                    event="change" />

                            </p:selectOneMenu>
                        </p:column>
                    </p:row>
                    <p:row rendered="#{testBean.field2 > 0}">
                        <p:column>
                            <h:outputText value="Field3:" />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <p:inputText
                                value="#{testBean.field3}"
                                size="5"
                                maxlength="10" />
                        </p:column>
                    </p:row>
                </p:panelGrid>
                <p:commandButton
                    value="Save"
                    binding="{save}"
                    action="#{testBean.saveForm()}"
                    process="@form" />
            </p:panel>
        </p:outputPanel>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

This approach is proposed by this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19712743/skip-required-validation-and-invoke-the-application).

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to use [omnifaces](http://omnifaces.org/), there is an [`ignoreValidationFailed`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/taghandlers/ignoreValidationFailed) tag.

Check the example at omnifaces showcase:

```
<o:form>
  ...
  <h:commandButton value="save valid data" action="#{bean.saveValidData}">
    <o:ignoreValidationFailed />
    <f:ajax execute="@form" />
  </h:commandButton>

</o:form>
```